# Linq statement to make a list of Int to a list of list of int .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, functional-programming

I have a list of integer [1,2,3,4....100]. 
I would like to use Linq statement to make it become a new list: 
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]....[99,100]]
or [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5].....[98,99,100]]
depending the size from the user input. Is that possible to do that with linq in VB.NET?

---

In response to Enigmativity's request:

Given a list of objects, I would like to use Linq to apply a function to every 3 consecutive items in the list, then aggregate them to get the final answer: here is an example: Original list: List of Point2D (each point has X and Y coordinate), in that list, take every 2 consecutive points (pi,pj) then take pi.X^2 + pj.Y^2, put all these values to a new list, then finally take the sum of the final list

Comment: You shouldn't edit a question to alter its history - this isn't a wiki. You need to keep the answers understandable to the question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy. Try this:

```
Dim build As Func(Of Integer, Integer()()) = Function (n) _
    Enumerable _
        .Range(1, 100)
        .Take(100 - n) _
        .Select(Function (x) Enumerable.Range(x, n).ToArray()) _
        .ToArray()

Dim result = build(2)
```

Just put whatever valid number you want as the parameter for `build` and it works.

---

Does this work for your revised question?

```
Dim query = _
    points _
        .Zip(points.Skip(1), Function (p0, p1) p0.X * p0.X + p1.Y * p1.Y) _
        .Sum()
```

Please note that your question isn't very clear as you talk about select 3 points, but then your example only uses 2.

Comment: Thank you, I think I should have made my original question a bit clearer. In the question, I only take an integer list as an example. But my goal was: given a list of objects, I would like to use Linq to apply a function to every 3 consecutive items in the list, then aggregate them to get the final answer: here is an example: 
Original list: List of Point2D (each point has X and Y coordinate), in that list, take every 2 points (p1,p2) then take p1.X^2 + p2.Y^2, put all these values to a new list, then finally take the sum of the final list.

Comment: @N.T.C - That's fine, but you should edit your question or ask a new one. It's not the done thing to ask it in a comment - especially to a comment in an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity- that works perfectly. Now for a broader pictures, for example, if the calculations involve 3 consecutive items, I guess I would have to use points.Zip(points.Skip(1),points.Skip(2), Function(p0,p1,p2) .... )  ? And I am not sure if this is way slower than using the normal For Loop. I could do the normal for loop but I've been trying to apply Functional programming in VB.NEt

Comment: @N.T.C - If you wanted to use `Zip` for more than two you would need to chain them together (which gets tedious). You are better off downloading the Microsoft Reactive Framework team's "Interactive Extensions" (NuGet "Ix-Main") which has a very good `Buffer` operator for enumerables. You could then do `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Buffer(3, 1).Take(10 - 2)` which will make groups of threes. The first parameter of `Buffer` is the count per group. Download it - you'll find many useful enumerable operators.